# Python BeautifulSoup - Grab internal links from page

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I have a basic loop to look for links on a page i have retrieved with urllib2.urlopen, however i am trying to only follow internal links on a page..

Any ideas how to make my below loop get only links that are on the same domain?

```
for tag in soupan.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}): 
                webpage = urllib2.urlopen(tag['href']).read()
                print 'Deep crawl ----> ' +str(tag['href'])
                try:
                    code-to-look-for-some-data...

                except Exception, e:
                    print e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print urllib.splithost.__doc__
splithost('//host[:port]/path') --> 'host[:port]', '/path'.
```

if the host is the same or the host is empty(which is for relative paths) the url belongs to the same host.

```
for tag in soupan.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):

            href = tag['href']
            protocol, url = urllib.splittype(href) # 'http://www.xxx.de/3/4/5' => ('http', '//www.xxx.de/3/4/5')
            host, path =  urllib.splithost(url)    # '//www.xxx.de/3/4/5' => ('www.xxx.de', '/3/4/5')
            if host.lower() != theHostToCrawl and host != '':
                continue

            webpage = urllib2.urlopen(href).read()

            print 'Deep crawl ----> ' +str(tag['href'])
            try:
                code-to-look-for-some-data...

            except:
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
```

because you do this

```
'href': re.compile("^http://")
```

no relative paths will be used.
the are like

```
<a href="/folder/file.htm"></a>
```

maybe do not use re at all?

Comment: Not sure i understand how to implement that into my loop, i see the logic though :) Do you know how to implement it into the loop?

Comment: You say not use `re` at all, but you could come up with a regular expression that matches `http://whatever` and `(no http://)`

Answer (score 0):

Some advice for your crawler: Use mechanize in combination with BeautifulSoup, that will simplify a lot your task.